# TFS Build/MSBuild 2010 bin folder auto redirection to binaries folder not redirecting all projects

Tags: build, msbuild, build-process, build-automation

I have TFS2010 build workflow that compiles our solution which contains ~100 projects.  Compilation is successful, tests run as expected etc.  The issue I have relates to the redirection of the bin output folders.

As I understand it, the TFS2010 build activity for MSBuild redriects your bin folder output to a binaries folder at the the same level as the Sources and TestResults folders as shown below.

C:\Builds\1\MyPlatform\MyPlatform Main - CI\Binaries

C:\Builds\1\MyPlatform\MyPlatform Main - CI\Sources

C:\Builds\1\MyPlatform\MyPlatform Main - CI\TestResults

This redirection of the bin folder works as expected for 80% of my projects.  The remaining projects bin folders appear unredirected in their standard location as if I was compiling using VS on a local machine.

To illustrate, when working as expected...

Source path:-

C:\Builds\1\MyPlatform\MyPlatform Main - CI\Sources\Source\MyPlatform.Modules.Interaction.Specs

Bin output succesfully redirected to the binaries folder :-

C:\Builds\1\MyPlatform\MyPlatform Main - CI\Binaries\Mixed Platforms\Debug\MyPlatform.Modules.Interaction.Specs

and now a non redirected example...

Source path :-

C:\Builds\1\MyPlatform\MyPlatform Main - CI\Sources\Source\MyPlatform.AddIns.Framework.Services

Bin output not redirected and remains in the source folder:-

C:\Builds\1\MyPlatform\MyPlatform Main - CI\Sources\Source\MyPlatform.AddIns.Framework.Services\bin\Debug

To clarify, this is not an issue with the drop location but the redirection of bin output to the intermediate Binaries folder.  The copy to my final drop location works as expected, all be it minus the projects whos bin output wasn't initially redirected to the binaries folder.

I've had a good look around and all information I've seen points towards customising the output to the binaries folder or relates to the drop location.  Having read this, I can't see anything that should cause some projects to ignore the default redirection.

Most of my projects are standard .NET 4 class libraries although there are a couple of c++ projects and a WIX installer.  I initially though it would be related to this difference but this problem is occuring on several .NET 4 class libraries that have identical settings to all the other projects that redirect successfully.

One more point about the example paths above. I've substituted "My" for actual project prefixes but otherwise paths are as used.

Does anyone know why some projects bin output might not be redirected?

Any help you can offer would be appreciated.

Thanks
H

Comment: Continued investigations and a shove in the right direction from Dharmesh Shah on MSDN revealed this was all related to the "TeamBuildOutDir" setting.  More details can be found here http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jimlamb/archive/2010/04/13/customizableoutdir-in-tfs-2010.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Continued investigations and a shove in the right direction from Dharmesh Shah on MSDN revealed this was all related to the "TeamBuildOutDir" setting. More details can be found here http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jimlamb/archive/2010/04/13/customizableoutdir-in-tfs-2010.aspx